# How to make BOTH bullets that hit each other in the same pygame.sprite.Group?

Tags: python, pygame, sprite

I have a class called `Bullets` and these objects are able to destroy other sprites when it hits them using `pygame.sprite.spritecollide()`. My issue is that I want the bullets to 'cancel out', i.e. to destroy each other when they hit, but `spritecollide()` only kills one of them and I need both gone. Is there a way to do this with `spritecollide()` or do I need something else?

Comment: Could you show me your collision code? I tend not to use the `dokill` argument or even the `sprite` methods in Pygame because it gets confusing quickly in the code. Simple `collide_rect()` functions a lot better.

Answer (score 1):

You can pass a custom callback function to `pygame.sprite.spritecollide` or `groupcollide` as the `collided` argument. In this case I use `groupcollide` and pass the `bullets` group twice. The `bullet_collision` callback function has just the purpose to check that the two sprites are not the same object.

```
import pygame as pg
from pygame.math import Vector2


pg.init()

BG_COLOR = pg.Color('gray12')
BULLET_IMG = pg.Surface((9, 15))
BULLET_IMG.fill(pg.Color('aquamarine2'))


class Bullet(pg.sprite.Sprite):

    def __init__(self, pos, *sprite_groups):
        super().__init__(*sprite_groups)
        self.image = BULLET_IMG
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect(center=pos)
        self.pos = pg.math.Vector2(pos)
        self.vel = pg.math.Vector2(0, -450)

    def update(self, dt):
        self.pos += self.vel * dt
        self.rect.center = self.pos
        if self.rect.bottom <= 0 or self.rect.top > 600:
            self.kill()


# Pass this callback function to `pg.sprite.groupcollide` to
# replace the default collision function.
def bullet_collision(sprite1, sprite2):
    """Return True if sprites are colliding, unless it's the same sprite."""
    if sprite1 is not sprite2:
        return sprite1.rect.colliderect(sprite2.rect)
    else:  # Both sprites are the same object, so return False.
        return False


class Game:

    def __init__(self):
        self.clock = pg.time.Clock()
        self.screen = pg.display.set_mode((800, 600))

        self.all_sprites = pg.sprite.Group()
        self.bullets = pg.sprite.Group()

        self.done = False

    def run(self):
        while not self.done:
            dt = self.clock.tick(30) / 1000
            self.handle_events()
            self.run_logic(dt)
            self.draw()

    def handle_events(self):
        for event in pg.event.get():
            if event.type == pg.QUIT:
                self.done = True
            if event.type == pg.MOUSEBUTTONDOWN:
                if event.button == 1:
                    Bullet(pg.mouse.get_pos(), self.all_sprites, self.bullets)
                    # A second bullet with inverted velocity.
                    bullet2 = Bullet(pg.mouse.get_pos()-Vector2(0, 400),
                                     self.all_sprites, self.bullets)
                    bullet2.vel = pg.math.Vector2(0, 450)

    def run_logic(self, dt):
        self.all_sprites.update(dt)
        # Groupcollide with the same group.
        # Pass the bullet_collision function as the `collided` argument.
        hits = pg.sprite.groupcollide(
            self.bullets, self.bullets,
            True, True, collided=bullet_collision)

    def draw(self):
        self.screen.fill(BG_COLOR)
        self.all_sprites.draw(self.screen)

        pg.display.flip()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    Game().run()
    pg.quit()
```